# To repeat variables in htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess that needs some modification. My site is able to show multiple category within a URL so that items in different category can be shown to user at the same time. Example would be like domain.com/fans.php?cat[]=1&cat[]=2&cat[]=3

To make this URL friendly, I add into my htaccess one line for 1 category, another line for 2 category and another for 3 category and more. As shown below

```
RewriteRule ^fans/category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ fans.php?cat=$1
```

**the above will become domain.com/fans/category/1**

```
RewriteRule ^fans/category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)&([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ fans.php?cat[]=$1&cat[]=$2
```

**the above will become domain.com/fans/category/1&2**

```
RewriteRule ^fans/category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)&([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)&([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ fans.php?cat[]=$1&cat[]=$2&cat[]=$3
```

**the above will become domain.com/fans/category/1&2&3**

My question is, what if I need to show 4 category or even 10 category? Is there a way to simplify rewrite rules in htacesss that will allow n times of category combine? or do I have to keep repeating like what I am doing above.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have one rule as long as there are enough optional regex groups, and empty keys (`cat[]=`) are not a problem . Example for 3 parameters maximum:

Request: `http://example.com/fans/category/1&2&3`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^fans/category/([^&]+)&?([^&]+)?&?([^&]+)?$ /fans.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2&cat3=$3 [L,NC]
```

However, when there are many parameters, it's better and more versatile to pass the complete URI-path with parameters to the script, using a single rewrite rule. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^fans/category/(.*) /fans.php?$1 [L,NC]
```

And get the parameters in the script with a code similar to this one:

```php
<?php 
$Query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$Parameters = explode ('&', $Query);
echo "cat1 = ". $Parameters[0] . "<br />";
echo "cat2 = ". $Parameters[1] . "<br />";
echo "cat3 = ". $Parameters[2] . "<br />";
...
?>
```

There are several ways to achieve the same result in php and maybe there is a better one, this is just an example.